# calling subclass method after initialising to parent java

Tags: java

This might (most certainly will) sound stupid, but I am stuck and I cant find a proper solution to my problem.
I have a superclass and two sub classes extend it. On the parent class based on a condition I want to call the method from either of the two classes. This is inside a loop, so instead of doing the same check I decided to do the check once, create an object from the super class and then change the object to either one of the two sub classes. i.e.

```
public class Parent{
    public void method() {
        Parent object=new Parent();
        if(a==b) {
            object=new Child_A();
        }else {
            object=new Child_B();
        }
        for() {
            object.method();
        }
    }
    public void method() {
        //empty method. need it just to compile
    }
}

public class Child_A extends Parent{
    public void method() {
        //do something useful
    }
}

public class Child_A extends Parent{
    public void method() {  
        //do something useful
    }
}
```

I had to write the Parent.method(), cos otherwise the compile would complain that there is no method() method on class Parent.
So with this, the method called is not one of the children,but the parents method.
I have read that objects need to be assigned directly to the class, like `Childen_A object=new Childen_A`. The thing is that I would like to use the same command for both cases (`object.method()`) no matter which class it refers to. Strange thing is that during debug, i see that object is of type Child_A, nevertheless the super method is called.
I know that the solution would be to create two different objects, one for each sub class, but that would make my code a bit more ugly and i would have to use the if statement inside the loop.So the correct way of doing it must be

```
public void method() {
   for() {
       if(a=b) {
            Child_A object=new Child_A();
            object.method();
       }else {
            Child_B() object=new Child_B();
            object.method();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the if statement inside the loop? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you should **overwrite** the `method` in the child classes. A parent should almost never know of its / actually care about / or even create instances of its child classes.

Comment: `if(a=b)` that's an assignment, not a condition.

Comment: Hmm Best solution : read more about inheritance and overriding and how to link both using polymorphism. You can get some workable solutions for the current approach, but best is you avoid using the current one. There should be 3rd entity (class) which should manage the object creation. Parent class even knowing the names of its sub class implies a BAD dependency of parent class on its sub class. Avoid it.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart edit it.

Comment: @nits.kk The code was almost done using just one class, no inheritance or anything. then this need aroused, so i had to think of a way around it. creating a third class handling the execution and keeping these three as is, was way too much hassle right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be

```
public class Parent {

    public void method() {

    }

    // OR

    public abstract void method(); // and make the class abstract as well
}

public class Child_A extends Parent {

    @Override
    public void method() {
        //do something useful
    }
}

// same with Child_B
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I had the impresion that inheriting methods overwrite the super methods by default. dont remember using the  @Override notation that often. thanks again

Comment: @SkarosIlias it does overwrite it if the name matches. `@Override` just ensures that you do not break your code via typos or refactoring.

Comment: It does have the same name and same parameters, even the return type. looks strange to me. anyway, thanks again